# How to show a page where a DIV is with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a DIV in the page index.html:

```
<div id="form"></div>
```

Now I need a way with jQuery to show another page inside that DIV.
The page I need to call and load there is contact.php
It is a simple HTML + PHP contact form.
Is there a way to load with jQuery the contents of contact.php inside index.html page where the DIV is?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").load("contact.php");
```

The jQuery `load` function fetches data from the server (in this case from `contact.php`) and replaces the contents of the selected element (in this case `#form`) with that data.

If necessary, you can also pass data into the page being loaded, and also supply a callback function that will be executed upon completion.

For more information, see the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: What if contact.php is set up to emit `<html>`, `<body>` etc. tags?

Comment: This solution is stripping out all the javascript codes inside the contact.php file. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Stripping is not exact. It does completely remove any javascript code inside the loaded page. How do I avoid the .load doing this?

Comment: I would suggest moving the JavaScript out, into an external `.js` file, and then loading that with `getScript`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Would be good. But I cannot do it.. The javascript must be loaded in the contact.php file. I was thinking about ajax .get. Would that work?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It does answer the question. Fair enough, it does not answer the question in the comments, but it answers the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use an `<iframe>` element. It would look something like this:

```
<iframe id="form" src="contact.php"></iframe>
```

This will load contact.php in a separate frame within your index.html, and you can style `iframe#form` in the same way that you would style a `<div>`.

Comment: What's this got to do with jQuery, or even JavaScript?

Comment: I must admit the iframe it is not the best solution at all.

Comment: @James That doesn't mean it isn't a solution to OP's problem. It isn't clear from the description that dynamic loading is actually necessary.

Comment: @Karl - The phrase in the question "I need a way with jQuery..." is what I was going on. (I didn't downvote by the way).

Comment: @James Allardice Is that a rhetorical question? My answer has nothing to do with jQuery. Looks like I entirely missed the point of the question.

Comment: @Calvin - Sorry, yes, it was a rhetorical question, I was just trying to point out that the OP asked for a jQuery solution.