# jQuery show ax external PHP page in a DIV

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show a page where a DIV is with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634903/how-to-show-a-page-where-a-div-is-with-jquery)

Hello I have a DIV in the page index.html:

```
<div id="form"></div>
```

Now I need a way with jQuery to show another page inside that DIV.
The page I need to call and load there is contact.php
It is a simple HTML + PHP contact form.
Is there a way to load with jQuery the contents of contact.php inside index.html page where the DIV is?

**Please remember that the contact.php page contains some javascript codes that must be fully working. So propably the jQuery.load function will not work in this case.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you show your pages?

Comment: There is no need to ask a new question. You can edit your original question to add these two sentences.

Comment: not possible, it IS duplicate.

Comment: @genesis: The comment is automatically generated when voted to close a question ;)

Comment: Whoops sorry @Felix, I'm not big enough to know it :)

Comment: @Felix, if you make a comment linking to the same question before voting to close, it'll suppress the automatic post - so you could do an "exact duplicate of ..." comment first. Probably not worth the bother though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get("contact.php", function(data){ $("#form").html(data); });
```

If your contact.php is a full page (including `<html>`), you should consider loading it in an `<iframe/>`.

**EDIT** If `$.get` does not work as above, you could try this:

```
$.get('example.html', function(data) {
        var $page = $(data);
        $page.filter('script').add($page.find('script')).each(function(){
            $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });
        $('#form').html(data);
    }
});
```

If `$.get` works as `.load`, script are ignored. With this code we're forcing them to be executed.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It gives me an error missing ) after argument list in Firebug

Comment: can you fix this error? Please.....

Comment: It's fixed now, I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

why won't jQuery.load work with javascript? It works great, you just have to use

```
$(function(){
     //your things
});
```

in ajax called page

you can fill your div with

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'conteact.php', 
        success: function(data){ $("#form").html(data); }

    });
});
```

Comment: No the jQuery.load delete any javascript code that is inside the contact.php page. In the final index.html all the javascript codes inside contact.php does not work at all. But I need them there. I cannot move the javascript codes from the contact.php page

Comment: however, javascript IS exected with .load() !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AJAX and the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').load('/contact.php');
});
```

If `contact.php` contains javascript code, this code will also work and be executed.

For example if `contact.php` looks like this:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#foo').html('some dynamic content');
</script>
```

the resulting DOM will look like this after the AJAX call:

```
<div id="form"><div id="foo">some dynamic content</div></div>
```

Comment: the `.load()` method ignores any `<script>` tag in the loaded content, (it's in the jquery source), that's why DiegoP asked not to use `.load()`

Comment: @Edgar Villegas Alvarado, I have just tested this code and believe me, it didn't ignore anything. It worked like a charm and the script was executed. Please test your code before claiming something and most importantly before downvoting.

Comment: It does not work for me. I need to call an external javascript code from another website in the contact.php file. This is why it does not work. I need an help here.

Comment: @DiegoP., which version of jQuery are you using? I have tested with 1.5.1 and it worked with inline and external javascript. Also is this contact.php script part of your domain?

Comment: the latest. And it does not work. I tried and tried. It completely ignored.

Comment: @DiegoP., is contact.php part of your domain?

Comment: @Darin, It's a `.load()` known issue, if you look at jquery source code it manually strips the `<script>` tags. I didn't invent it

Comment: Yes sure it is. The structure is: index.html and contact_lib/contact.php

Comment: @Edgar Villegas Alvarado, then why does it work when I test it? By the way did you test it yourself?

Comment: @Darin Not now, but it happened to me once.